# Parameterise settings.json of Function app for publish

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, publish-profiles

For a Proof of Concept, I would like to publish an Azure Function from Visual studio to Azure with a different `connectionString` value. But I can't figure out how.

In the `FunctionApp` there is a `local.settings.json` file. I have added a `connectionString` to my local database.

`local.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=declapp;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

I can publish this `FunctionApp` to Azure with the generated publish profile but I have a database in Azure which is used by the deployed `FunctionApp`. The first time I had to add the `connectionString` to the FunctionApp in the Azure Portal. But also when the `connectionString` needs to be altered, I can only do it in the Azure Portal.

I would like to know how I can add/alter the `connectionString` in the publishing part as below. How can I achieve this?

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<Azure sql connectionstring>"
  }
}
```

Just to be clear: I know it`s a bad practice to have (production) values in source control, but it's for a simple Proof of Concept and I don't want to define a CI/CD pipeline just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local.settings.json` is only intended for local development. In Azure, the values will be taken from App Settings of your Function App.

You can set this settings e.g. via the portal, Azure CLI ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_set)), ARM templates ([example](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-define-web-app-application-settings/)), or func CLI from `local.app.settings` (`func azure functionapp publish MyApp --publish-settings-only`).

Comment: So I need to add an App Settings file to the function project? Or can I make something as a `tst.settings.json` and use this in the publish profile?

Comment: For Proof-of-concept I would just set them in the portal. Added more options with links to the answer.

Comment: This is also something we are tracking to improve in future https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/595